# Can we mix between OIDC authentication and basic authentication in Quarkus?

Tags: keycloak, resteasy, quarkus, quarkus-oidc

I am building rest services by Quarkus, I have some endpoints that are authenticated by keycloak, but some are authenticated by basic authentication. Can I do that in Quarkus ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: According to the docs, you can do that, as long as you combine basic and keycloak's token authentication. https://quarkus.io/guides/security#combining-authentication-mechanisms